# What if EXE and DLL have different MEMORY ALIGNMENT?

Tags: memory-alignment

In VC, I have an DLL file with memory alignment set as 1, and an EXE file memory alignment set as default (it's 4). And I use classes of this DLL in EXE. Is there any potential risk with different memory alignment sets?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by "memory alignment" you mean "structure packing" (/Zp).  Yes, there can be problems if you have structures which require padding to achieve the specified alignment, since the two modules will pad differently.

Comment: Yes that's what i meant. Padding is used in a method of class of this DLL, and it will be called in EXE. Which alignment will it use? Thanks.

Comment: Each module will use the packing it was compiled with. If a class or structure is shared, and the two sides made different padding decisions, then bad things will happen. Not sure what part of this was not obvious.